# Resolving "Cannot read property 'unprefixed' of undefined" on npm run serve with animate.css package

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, animate.css

I am developing an application using Vue, Quasar, and the animate.css package for CSS animations in my website. Everything has been going smoothly until recently I was having an issue with the `npm run build` command, which leads to the error in the title. Upon some investigation, I tried to install the `postcss-rtlcss` package, which led to this error occurring on `npm run serve` as well. Please note that I am relatively new to the Vue and node.js ecosystem, so please let me know if I am doing something completely wrong.

The error upon running `npm run serve`

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                          10:28:49 PM

error  in ./node_modules/animate.css/animate.css

Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'unprefixed' of undefined


 @ ./node_modules/animate.css/animate.css 4:14-163 15:3-20:5 16:22-171
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://10.0.0.251:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

In addition to this, here is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "socialapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "quasar": "^2.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.1.4",
    "vue-body-class": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.45.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "postcss-rtl": "^1.2.3",
    "sass": "1.32.12",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-quasar": "~4.0.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Please let me know in a comment if you need anything else from me and I will try my best to provide it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, I may not be able to provide an update right away as it is night time in my region as of the time of posting of this question, so please be patient! Thanks :)

Comment: Try bumping the version of `postcss-rtl` to `^3.3.0`, `1.2.3` is super old

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I tried changing to `^3.3.0` in package.json, but `npm i` tells me that there is no matching version for `postcss-rtl@^3.3.0`. It looks like the most recent version is `1.7.3`, to which I have updated now. I still receive the same error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by downgrading my PostCSS version to `^7.0.36` in package.json. While this may cause issues in the dependency tree, when I tried to install with the `--force` argument, it worked just fine. All commands work fine now.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using **postcss** version 8, then make sure you also have the latest verison of **postcss-preset-env**, as you would not want to downgrade postcss due to security issues associated with version less than 8

```
"postcss-preset-env": "^7.2.3"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following resolved this for me.

```
"resolutions": {
  "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
  "postcss": "^8.2.12",
}
```

You can use `yarn why [package]` to figure out whether any of these are currently directly or indirectly installed and with what version.

Answer (score 0):

update "postcss-rtl" to 2.0.0